# Qt Layouts for 3 panels, all vertically expanding to fill

Tags: c++, qt, pyqt, pyside

I am rather new to desktop GUI development.

I am trying to get a frame with 3 parallel vertical panels, all expanding vertically to fill the window.

I want the first two panels not to be flexible but to have a fixed size.

Ex:

```
 Fixed W.
|========|
############################ 
#    #    #                # ^
#Fix.#Fix.#                # |
#|--|#|--|# <--Flexible--> # Flexible vertically all 3 panels.
#    #    #                # |
#    #    #                # v
############################
```

How can I obtain this layout? I am tried Grid, Vertical, Horizontal but I think I got it all spaghetti-like and confused.

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need a

```
QHBoxLayout
```

You just have to set a fixed width for your fixed widgets (in the left).

Here is a complete working example in C++:

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QtGui>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    QFrame* w1 = new QFrame;
    w1->setFixedWidth(100);
    w1->setStyleSheet("background-color: red");

    QFrame* w2 = new QFrame;
    w2->setFixedWidth(100);
    w2->setStyleSheet("background-color: blue");

    QFrame* w3 = new QFrame;
    w3->setStyleSheet("background-color: green");
    w3->setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy::Expanding, QSizePolicy::Expanding);

    QHBoxLayout* layout = new QHBoxLayout;

    layout->addWidget(w1);
    layout->addWidget(w2);
    layout->addWidget(w3);

    QWidget* app = new QWidget;
    app->setLayout(layout);
    app->show();
    return a.exec();
}
```

And the screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Thank you @Kikohs!! Excellent quality help.